# Voltage regulator stability, PMOS v NMOS pass transistor

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, simulation, stability

Currently, I am considering some LDO replacement circuits because some parts have bad availability.

For small current demands (up to maybe 20 mA) I think, a simple opamp will do fine, but for larger currents, a stronger pass transistor is needed. Despite the numerous advantages of P-type pass elements (lower drop-out, simpler startup and shutdown), it is often said, that P-MOSFET will be less stable and so I was going to give it a try. This is the basic circuit I will refer to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTzcSc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First please ignore the capacitors. In this simple case, there is only the opamp, the pass transistor and the load. In both cases, a change in the load will cause the same differential voltage on the opamp and it will respond in the same way. There seems to be no difference between both circuits.

At high frequencies, there is a difference, because the capacitance through the MOSFET adds negative feedback for the NMOS, but adds positive feedback for the PMOS. However, as the output node has very low impedance to GND at frequencies above ~10 kHz due to the usual output caps, this is inconsequential. Indeed the simulation in CircuitLab shows roughly the same supply impedance for the output nodes for both pass transistors. It doesn't show resonances for either circuit.

### Some more LTspice simulations

After it was commented that the models in CircuitLab may not be accurate enough, I am using some models of the actual opamp I want to use from the manufacturer. I also replaced the reference voltage source with a Zener diode. The circuits are otherwise identical. The AC analysis yields identical curves for the N and P type circuits. I also could confirm that when the output current is very low (µAs) the circuit has trouble equilibrating as it has no way to reduce the voltage.

[image]

The load on the output causes 50 mA load steps, which was suggested by Bimpelrekkie. The following plot show the output responses to these load steps.

[image]

Both circuits show a similar response, the N circuit is a tiny bit faster, but also oscillates a bit more.

With a slightly more mundane output capacitance network (0.1 µF, 280mohm ESR, 20 nH ESL and 0.4 µF ceramic in parallel), it just so happens that the P type is stable, but the N type is not:

[image]

I should note, that these transistors both have a \$R_{on}=6\Omega\$. When using lower resistance MOSFET, *both* circuits become much more unstable, and both can be tamed again by inserting an additional resistor of a couple Ohm at the source of the respective MOSFET.

### Question:

So, what is the actual problem with the PMOS circuit that makes it less stable? Under which conditions does this problem actually occur or is it rather academic in nature (i.e. it won't appear with usual output loading) ?

I know that there is a lot of discussion on this available, but unfortunately it uses heavy electrical engineering language which I cannot understand. I am looking ideally for a time domain based explanation and nothing based on phase margin, poles, zeros, common source circuits etc. because all the things mean little to me. If they are vital for the explanation, it would be nice to explain how and why.

Comment: The fact that you don't see much difference could mean that the opamp's model is unrealistic. The "common drain" (left) circuit is more easy to design as the **pole** it introduces is quite high frequency (result of the common-drain's low output impedance). While the common source adds (loop) gain and a pole (a common drain is a current output so high output impedance). Understanding this does require knowledge of poles, loopgain and phase margins etc. I suggest that you try the circuits also on a breadboard and see what you get.

Comment: A common way to judge stability in the time domain is by looking at the **step response**. Make the load current suddenly change (like in less than 1 us) from 100 mA to 110 mA. What does the response (output voltage) look like? For proper regulation I want no more than 2 sinusoidal shapes. If in your simulator the response for both circuits are equal then you indeed have modeling issues as there **must** be a difference. I would not trust the simulator if there was not.

Comment: Thanks, Bimpelrekkie. Although you used almost exclusively terms which I have yet to comprehend, at least it stimulates me to try and understand them. If you read again my 3rd paragraph (which you tell is wrong), why would the output impedance be different between the two circuits, so why does it matter which way the FET points when its transconductance is the same ?

Comment: Hmm, to understand that you have to study **small signal analysis**. The common drain has a lower output impedance because it has "local feedback". Imagine that the gate is at some voltage and more current is pulled from the source. That then lowers the source voltage a bit and in turn increases the \$V_{GS}\$ of the MOSFET, opening it more and making it deliver more current. More current pulled => MOSFET opened more. This is done by the MOSFET itself. This doesn't happen when the MOSFET is used as a common Source. Then the opamp has to increase \$V_{GS}\$.

Comment: Practical tip: **if** you have enough voltage headroom (\$V_{in} - V_{out}\$ > 5 V for example) then I would definately choose the common drain (the left circuit). But yeah, that doesn't make it an LDO.

Comment: That sounds very intuitive, thanks. I will try more with step responses in LTspice then.. The responses look definitely different, I would say almost "out of phase", but in general the P-type circuit is not less stable.

Comment: *but in general the P-type circuit is not less stable* You might be in a "lucky" situation. Also try with different load currents. The common source will usually be most instable at **low** load currents as that increases the loopgain. The common drain is much less sensitive to the load current.

Comment: Stability will be much better with the n-MOS version. As others said, test with step voltages and step load currents. You might still need to add some compensation. It's very far from being an LDO though. If you can give the op-amp a supply that's several volts higher than the drain voltage you can make the dropout voltage low relative to the drain voltage.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I tested with some load steps and updated the post. Of course I could be lucky, but I am using a very usual load configuration I believe. Do you have some ideas, which elements could be changed, to make the stability advantage of the n-type circuit more pronounced?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany "Stability will be much better with the n-MOS version." I believe so, and I would probably use an N-type regulator in practise to satisfy this gut feeling, but I am unable to reproduce this difference with sims. I have added more sims, and actually they show no difference for the same loading or the P-type response could be even a bit *more* stable.

Comment: Is that 1000uF Cbulk with 5nH series inductance realistic?

Comment: Indeed, with such a large output cap (1mF) indeed you wouldn't see much difference as that cap would "eat up" any disturbances so the regulator basically doesn't "see" the load change. Such a large cap at the output means you will get a pole at a very low frequency and as such it will be the dominant pole. The loopgain will be less than 1 for all other poles in the circuit and it will always be stable. You could indeed go for this option and be happy :-) My comments above get more relevant when you have a much smaller cap at the output like a few uF in total.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am not sure, I think it is not so far off. 3-4 small electrolytics in parallel don't have such a large loop. Anyway, I have added another plot with 50 nH. The ringing becomes more severe as expected, but again the P-type is more stable.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie indeed removing the electrolytics and with only 0.1 - 1 µF instead, both circuits become pretty unstable (the ripple of the P type is still lower). This is what you get for most opamp outputs anyway and one has to compensate for it or snub it (i.e. electrolytic cap). Without the electrolytics to snub this resonance, of course matters become delicate. I presume the necessary loop compensation is easier done for the N-type circuit ? Is that the essence ? Does it mean then, that the difference erodes when using electrolytics to snub the resonance instead?

Comment: Don't use a snubber network to make things stable again! Instead fix the loop by adding a dominant pole. Yes, loop compensation is easier with the NMOS version as the PMOS version also has a pole at the output (see explanation above). So the PMOS version becomes  a 2-pole system while with the NMOS version it is easier to keep it single-pole. (Both systems have multiple poles, I only count the ones that are at frequencies where the loopgain > 1 as those can cause oscillations, I'm cutting corners here regarding my explanation, you might want to study this subject).

Comment: Some links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_compensation  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351139/understanding-of-dominant-pole-compensation  University level explanation: https://people.engr.tamu.edu/s-sanchez/457%20Stability%20Final.pdf  That will keep you busy ;-)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ok I think I am beginning to understand now. Thank you very much. Why do you oppose the resonance snubbing? As far as I know, it is a standard technique to design stable power supply nodes, i.e. add ceramic for the desired high frequency response, than add bulk capacitance with suitable ESR until there is no gain peaking. (add more bulk capacitance if a certain PSU impedance is necessary at medium frequency)

Comment: Yes, but snubbers are generally not part of (system with) a **regulation loop**. Also snubbers "eat up" the resonance but they don't deal with the root cause. And if due to component tolerances your snubber network is (slightly) off frequency then you'll have your resonances/oscillations back! I would use snubber networks for dealing with **resonances** that occur during **fast switching** (MOSFET on/off, SCRs etc) but not to prevent **oscillations** in a regulation loop.